# RecyclerView doesn't set adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have three recycler views in a fragment. I've set adapters for two of them. But, one recycler view inflates the card views but the other doesn't.

I've debugged the code and the adapter of the recycler view which doesn't show is not getting called.

This is my onViewCreated() method in the fragment

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerViewVendors = view.findViewById(R.id.rcyview_vendors);
        recyclerViewEvents = view.findViewById(R.id.rcyview_home_events);
        String json;
        try{

            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("vendorServices.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            if(is.read(buffer) == -1){
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray j_Array = object.getJSONArray("vendorServices");

            for(int i=0;i<j_Array.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo_inside = j_Array.getJSONObject(i);
                myDatasetVendors.add(new VendorService(
                        jo_inside.getString("name"),
                        jo_inside.getString("img")
                ));
            }


            is = getActivity().getAssets().open("activities.json");
            size = is.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            if (is.read(buffer) == -1) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }

            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray m_jArray = obj.getJSONArray("Activities");

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                myDatasetEvents.add(jo_inside.getString("title"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        layoutManagerVendors = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerViewVendors.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerVendors);

        mAdapterVendors = new AdapterVendorServices(myDatasetVendors, this.getContext());
        recyclerViewVendors.setAdapter(mAdapterVendors);

        layoutManagerEvents = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerViewEvents.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerEvents);

        mAdapterEvents = new AdapterHomeEvents(myDatasetEvents, this.getContext());
        recyclerViewEvents.setAdapter(mAdapterEvents);
    }
```

This is my adapter which doesn't get called

```
public class AdapterHomeEvents extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterHomeEvents.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    Context context;

    public AdapterHomeEvents(ArrayList<String> mDataset, Context context) {
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_home_events, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_crdViewHome_events);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to populate both of my recycle views with card views but it populate only one recycler view but it doesn't populate the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot to set size in your adapter:-

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
```